# Electron - extraResources files not found in MacOS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, electron, electron-builder

After the build with electron-builder the project does not start on the Mac, shows an error that it cannot find the files . I put them in extraResources and it works on Restore, but not in Mac
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xqjyh.jpg) that is, it searches for node_modules in the middle of app.asar, but need searches in the Resorces folder

```
"build": {
    "appId": "com.praveenp.name",
    "productName": "Name",
    "files": [
      "main/*.js",
      "renderer"
    ],
    "includeSubNodeModules": true,
    "extraFiles": [
      "renderer/next.config.js",
      "renderer/db.ts"
    ],
    "extraResources": [
      "prisma/**/*",
      "node_modules/react",
      "node_modules/.prisma/**/*",
      "node_modules/@prisma/client/**/*",
      "node_modules/@fortawesome"
    ],
    "nsis": {
      "oneClick": false,
      "perMachine": true,
      "allowElevation": true,
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
      "deleteAppDataOnUninstall": true,
      "createDesktopShortcut": true,
      "installerIcon": "build/icon.ico",
      "uninstallerIcon": "build/icon.ico"
    },
    "mac": {
      "publish": [
        "github"
      ],
      "icon": "public/images/logo.ico",
      "category": "public.app-category.finance",
      "target": {
        "target": "default",
        "arch": [
          "x64",
          "arm64"
        ]
      }
    },
  }
```

```
app.on('ready', async () => {

  const nextApp = next({
    dev: isDev,
    dir: app.getAppPath() + '/renderer'
  });
  const handle = nextApp.getRequestHandler();
  const port = 3000;

  await nextApp.prepare();

  createServer((req: any, res: any) => {
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
    handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
  }).listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
  })

  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    minWidth: 800,
    minHeight: 650,
    width: 1000,
    height: 800,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      contextIsolation: false,
    },
  });

  if (app.isPackaged) {
    mainWindow.setMenu(null);
  }
  await mainWindow.loadURL(`http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

I need everything in extraResources separately, because otherwise the application does not see the path.
So, the question is why it works on Windows, but on Mac the path to node_modules is wrong ?

Is there any other way to add extraResoruses?